# clearing exception stack frame when running interactively in Python

Tags: python, exception

How can I force destructors to be called on objects that went out of scope by an uncaught exception in an interactive Python session in a way that will also work in a script?

[sys.exc_clear()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exc_clear) works for caught exceptions in a script. For example, in the following script, the destructor is not triggered by the variable going out of scope, nor is it triggered by garbage collection; it is triggered by sys.exc_clear.

```
class A:
    def __del__(self):
        print 'obj deleted'

def test():
    a = A()
    raise Exception()

try:
    test()
except:
    pass

import gc
gc.collect(2)

print 'done test part 1'

import sys
sys.exc_clear()

print 'done test part 2'
```

The output is

```
done test part 1
obj deleted
done test part 2
```

If, on the other hand, this is run interactively except with just calling `test()` instead of the try-except block, the destructor is only called at exit or at the next exception.

I'm testing with Python 2.7.6, but I'd like a solution that works for at least 2.6+.